# Which port is my Azure Function App running on?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

When running an Azure Function App locally in Visual Studio, if the app contains an Http Function then when it starts the host console window prints the port it is running on.

If however the Function App does not contain an Http Function then the host console window does not print the port the host is running on.

However you need to know the port the host is running on in order to send it the http requests that are required to do things like triggering timer functions manually.

I can create an Http Function that my app doesn't need and enclose it in an `if DEBUG` preprocessor statement in order to know which port it is running on, but I'm wondering whether there is a way to do it that doesn't require creating code my application doesn't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To know which port your non-Http Azure function is listening to:***

`Open Solution explorer=>Right click on the project=> Select Properties=> Debug=> In general, click on open debug launch profiles UI`.
you can see the port number in the *command line arguments*.

To check the same, I have created a Queue trigger function and Timer trigger function.

***Queue Trigger function:***

[image]

***Timer trigger function:***

[image]

I have created Http Azure function to verify/confirm the same:

*Port number in function properties:*

[image]

*While running locally, Http function is listening to 7288:*

[image]